Is there a way to scale a tikzpicture, and choose specific values to not scale?
When writing tikzpictures, I like to use the same numbers for my coordinates as are in my notes. This sometimes results in an overly large tikzpicture. Scaling tikzpictures is considered by some to be bad practice, though I don't see a better way forward here - it would be difficult to scale them all down individually.
I am running into a problem where there are some numbers in the tikzpicture that I don't want to scale. So, is there a way to scale a tikzpicture, and choose specific values to not scale?
I tried using a circular node, but in practice, it cannot accommodate my minimum size.
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dontScaleMe{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    
     % I don't want to scale this circle. 
     % It should be big enough to touch the tip of the red line.
    \fill (2,3) circle[radius=\dontScaleMe cm];

    % the \dontScaleMe in the shorten syntax seems unaffected by scaling.
    \draw[shorten <=\dontScaleMe cm, red] (2,3) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Tikz scale should affect (1,1) but not (1cm,1cm).

A \node path won't be scaled. Unless you add option every node/.style={scale=<dim>}
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \node (c) at (2,3) [circle,minimum size=2cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,fill,opacity=0.4] {};
    \draw[shorten <= 1cm,red] (2,3) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \node (c) at (2,3) [circle,minimum size=2cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,fill,opacity=0.4] {};
    \draw[shorten <= 1cm,red] (2,3) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \node (c) at (2,3) [circle,minimum size=2cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,fill,opacity=0.4] {};
    \draw[shorten <= 1cm,red] (2,3) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Awesome, I was putting the node commands in the \node options, and now I know to put them after the coordinate. Thanks
